# how many trials required to make sure the relative frequency of an even falls within bound

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution

So I am pondering the following question: Suppose $A$ is an event which has the probability of 0.4 of occurring. How many trials must be performed to assert with probability 0.9 that the relative frequency of A differs from 0.4 by no more than 0.1.

Here is what I tried. Let

$$
S_n = \xi_1 + \cdots + \xi_n
$$
where each $\xi_i$ is the random variable which gives 1 if $A$ occurs and 0 otherwise. Then we are trying to determine the smallest $n$ for which
$$
P(|S_n/n - 0.4| > 0.1) \leq 0.1.
$$

By Chebyshev's inequality we have
$$
P(|S_n/n - 0.4| > 0.1) \leq \frac{(0.4 \cdot 0.6)}{n (0.1)^2} 
$$
and we want to make the right hand side smaller than 0.1. This yields the inequality
$$
10^3 \cdot (0.4 \cdot 0.6) = 240 \leq n
$$
which seems to say that we need $n$ to be at least about 240.

However, the book I am using claims the answer is about 65, which I am not sure where that is coming from. Is it the case that Chebyshev's inequality here is too crude and there are better ways of getting $n$?

Thanks!

edit: previously I misapplied Chebyshev's inequality getting a different lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chebyshev's inequality is for upper bound, which is not very exact. But you can use the central limit theorem. Basically the equation is

$$2\cdot \Phi\left(\frac{\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu}{\sqrt{Var\left(\frac{S_n}{n} \right)}} \right)-1=0.9$$

$$2\cdot \Phi\left(\frac{0.1}{\sqrt{\frac{0.4\cdot 0.6}{n}}} \right)-1=0.9$$

$2\cdot \Phi(x_0)-1$ is the area bounded by the interval from $-x_0$ to $x_0$ of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: So this is was another approach I took, and I believe I got the same formula, or at least something similar looking. The problem I had with this approach was how do you obtain $n$ from this equation? Does one just look at a table (or use WolframAlpha) to get an estimate?

Comment: Ok I did that and yeah it is roughly as the book says. Thanks!

Comment: @CWcx Nice, that you've found out by yourself.

Comment: I understand that $\Phi$ has an inverse since its smooth and monotone, I was just not sure if there was a explicit formula for the inverse, especially given $\Phi$ itself doesn't have a formula.

Comment: @CWcx Indeed there exists no closed formula for the function or even the inverse function. That's why tables have been made. In present you can use (online) calculators as well.